# オブジェクト作成する際、「Object.create」ではなく「new Object()」と書いた方が良いケースはある？

Tags: javascript

**前提**
・「Object.create」が使用できる環境

---

**オブジェクト作成する際、「Object.create」ではダメで「new Object()」でしか出来ないことはありますか？**
・「Object.create」は、完全な上位互換ですか？
・「Object.create」ではなく「new Object()」と書いた方が良いケースはある？
・「new Object()」は古い書き方なので、敢えて使用する必要はない？？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Object.create`ではコンストラクターが実行されません。

`new Test()`の動作

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.__proto__ = Test.prototype;
return Test.call(obj) || obj;
```

`Object.create(Test.prototype)`の動作

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.__proto__ = Test.prototype;
return obj;
```

例えば`new Date()`では現在時刻が得られますが`Object.create(Date.prototype)`では未初期化の`Date`オブジェクトが得られます。